# What is the type of load_iris in scikit-learn library in python?

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I am looking at the iris dataset as part of the sklearn datasets and when I assign the following:

```
> iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
```

writing the following gives me:

```
> type (iris)
  <class 'tuple'>
```

What exactly does it mean by a class of tuples? I have read the documentation but it is still not clear to me how you can access

```
> iris.data
```

and

```
> iris.target
```

but then how can you also do :

```
> iris.target[[10, 25, 50]]
```

Can someone please explain this in more detail? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For sklearn 0.19.1 `type(iris)` returns:

```
In [126]: type(iris)
Out[126]: sklearn.utils.Bunch
```

Let's see what does it mean under the hood:

```
In [127]: sklearn.utils.Bunch??
Init signature: sklearn.utils.Bunch(**kwargs)
Source:
class Bunch(dict):
    """Container object for datasets

    Dictionary-like object that exposes its keys as attributes.

    >>> b = Bunch(a=1, b=2)
    >>> b['b']
    2
    >>> b.b
    2
    >>> b.a = 3
    >>> b['a']
    3
    >>> b.c = 6
    >>> b['c']
    6

    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(kwargs)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # Bunch pickles generated with scikit-learn 0.16.* have an non
        # empty __dict__. This causes a surprising behaviour when
        # loading these pickles scikit-learn 0.17: reading bunch.key
        # uses __dict__ but assigning to bunch.key use __setattr__ and
        # only changes bunch['key']. More details can be found at:
        # https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6196.
        # Overriding __setstate__ to be a noop has the effect of
        # ignoring the pickled __dict__
        pass
File:           c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py
Type:           type

In [128]: sklearn.__version__
Out[128]: '0.19.1'
```

PS I hope it helps to understand what does it contain bit better

Answer (score 0):

The type(iris) returns sklearn.utils.Bunch.

But its actually a Dict with Keys as data,feature_names,target,target_names

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris=load_iris()

features=iris['data'] #u can use iris.data
label=iris['target'] #u can use iris.target 

model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
model.fit(features,label)

result=model.predict([[ 6.7,  2.5,  5.8,  1.8]])
```

has u can see in the code iris['data'] gives the features np array with data.

The iris['target'] gives the array of category to which they belong.

so the iris dataset loaded from sklearn is a **dict** containing features and labels.